# Параметр маршрута?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Добрый вечер уважаемые собеседники. Появилась необходимость прикрутить к системе регистрации реферальную ссылку вида: http://localhost:44321/Account/Register/**Name** где Name - имя пригласившего и его необходимо при переходе по реферальной ссылке сразу вносить в соответствующее поле при регистрации:

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-gift"></i></span>
                                <input asp-for="Referal" class="form-control" placeholder="@Localizer["Register.Referal"]" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Referal" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
```

Так вот вопрос, в какую сторону смотреть? Параметры маршрутов?

Comment: Ну а вы пробовали что либо? Ведь верно мыслите...

Comment: Здравствуйте. Нет, пока не пробовал. Это просто размышления и вопрос). Потому как я новичок в этом деле, изучаю и читаю. Поэтому и задал вопрос, чтобы не начать копать не туда)

Comment: Вы копаете туда, продолжайте в том же духе :)

Comment: Спасибо ребят за толчок)